# Change marker within leaflet map when loading data from geojson file

Tags: leaflet, geojson, web-mapping, json, mapping

This section of code adds markers to my map (it works), how can I change the marker to a different icon when dealing with geojson?

```
var cycleracks = $.getJSON('cycle-racks.geojson', function (geojson) {
  L.geoJson(geojson, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
      layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.type);
    }
  }).addTo(map);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this tutorial: http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons.html